# How pyspark integrates with java?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, jvm

**Disclaimer**

I do not know much of python, so the question describes "how it looks like" and the answer should be "how it actual works".

**Question**

`Pyspark` allows to run python code in `spark`. But `python` is interpreted language and it functionality depend on environemnt (e.g. 32 or 64 bit platform you run python code). While `spark` runs on jvm which run code independ on environemnt.

So how does `python` code "converted" into jvm byte code? Or it is not run on jvm? What technology is used? (CORBA?) I heard about `Jython` but it looks like independe technology which is not used in `pysaprk` is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark specifically uses Py4J for passing the python application code to run on the JVM. You can find more information here https://www.py4j.org/

You can find the internal architecture here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals